# split a matrix and save in separate variables in a loop

Tags: r, variables, matrix

I have a data which is a m*n matrix. I would like to split the matrix by column and save each column separately in a different vector.
E.g

```
data<-matrix(1:9, ncol=3)
```

I would like to have `vec1` containing the first column so

> `vec1` will be transpose of `[1,2,3]`, a column matrix with dimension 3*1 which is basically the first column of data. Similarly, `vec2` represents the 2nd column and `vec3` represents the last column.

I understand that I can do this manually by repeating

```
vec1<-data[,1], 
vec2<-data[,2] 
... 
vecn<-data[,n].
```

However, this is not feasible when n is large.
So I would like to know whether it is feasible to use a loop to do this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: This is a pretty terrible idea - sequentially named variables are much harder to work with than, say, a nice matrix. They don't scale well, they often lead to copy/paste and find/replace with bugs caused by typos.... Why do you want to do this? What is the bigger problem? Using a `list` is a nice way to keep them in a single object in case a matrix isn't suitable. You might want to read [How do I make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) for related discussion.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for your comment. I am working on a project in determining the position of an object in the next second using the data of the previous 10 seconds. The position of the object is determined by 10 joints and each joint has 3 coordinates. Therefore, I need to make predictions for all 30 coordinates in order to get the prediction. So what I intended to do is to use 30 variables to represent 30 coordinates and loop all the processes from data cleansing to modelling.

Comment: I think the structure of your code will be much easier if you use a single matrix or a single list to hold all 30 coordinates. Looping over columns of a matrix is highly optimized using the `apply` function - you will add complexity to your code and lose efficiency by taking variables out of a matrix. `data.frames` are particularly slow when compared to matrices.

Comment: And, I should add, that even if you need them as data frames to plug into some other function, you can just do `apply(your_matrix, 2, function(x) other_function(data.frame(X1 = x)))` without cluttering your workspace with `n` single-column data frames.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, this is probably not a good idea. However, if you still felt the need to proceed down this path, rather than using a `list` or just using the source `matrix` itself, the easiest approach would probably be to use a combination of `list2env` and `data.frame`.

Here's a demo, step-by-step:

```
data <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3)

ls()  # Only one object in my workplace
# [1] "data"

data_list <- unclass(data.frame(data))
str(data_list)
# List of 3
#  $ X1: int [1:3] 1 2 3
#  $ X2: int [1:3] 4 5 6
#  $ X3: int [1:3] 7 8 9
#  - attr(*, "row.names")= int [1:3] 1 2 3

ls() # Two objects now
# [1] "data"      "data_list"

list2env(data_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)

ls() # Five objects now
# [1] "data"      "data_list" "X1"        "X2"        "X3"  

X1
# [1] 1 2 3
```

---

If you want single-column `data.frame`s, you can use `split.list`:

```
list2env(setNames(split.default(data.frame(data), seq(ncol(data))), 
                  paste0("var", seq(ncol(data)))), envir = .GlobalEnv)
var1
#   X1
# 1  1
# 2  2
# 3  3
```

Putting this together, you can actually do this all at once (without first having to create "data_list") like this:

```
list2env(data.frame(data), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

But again, you should have a good reason to do so!

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, this is not what I intend to have. Similar result can be obtained by using a for loop ,assign and paste(). As in I want all v1, v2... has data.frame. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: @user9184644, What do you mean "this is not what I want"? X1, X2, and so on are your columns as individual vectors....

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let me try this.